# Does Luke 17:26–31 describe the destruction of Jerusalem?

Tags: luke, eschatology, jerusalem

In Luke 17:26–31, Jesus brings up Noah and the flood as well as Lot and Sodom, saying, “Even so will it be **in the day** when the Son of Man is revealed” (v. 30, NKJV, emphasis mine). Then, in the next verse, Jesus says, “**In that day** [i.e., the day of v. 30], he who is on the housetop, and his goods are in the house, let him not come down to take them away. And likewise the one who is in the field, let him not turn back” (v. 31, NKJV, emphasis mine).

Assuming Luke 17:26–31 describes the destruction of Jerusalem, would this mean that Jesus is comparing A.D. 70, rather than the end of the world, to the swift destruction during the days of the flood and of Sodom in Luke 17?

Comment: End of Israel (destruction, genocide) is end of the world. Both are not diff things. There are a few good topics on this site explaining the "Day of the Lord", by Ruminator. Similarly, the 1945 genocide of the Jews can also be called the same "end of world", as the number of deaths was nearly the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no question that Luke 17:20-37 has some remarkable parallels to the material in Luke 21 and the rest of the synoptic apocalypse (see Matt 24, Mark 13).

However, let us be very clear: the synoptic apocalypse contains prophecies about two closely related events:

- the destruction of Jerusalem, eg, Luke 21:20-24, AND
- the second coming of the Son of Man, eg, Luke 17: 20-37, Luke 21:25-28 (see also Matt 24:29-31, 36-41, etc).

While these events are distinct, Jesus' sermon in the synoptic apocalypse uses the destruction of the Jerusalem as a metaphor to teach about the coming of the Son of Man.  This is actually made explicit in the introduction:

> Matt 24:3 - While Jesus was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the
> disciples came to Him privately. “Tell us,” they said,
>
> - “when will these things [V2 about the destruction of the temple and Jerusalem] happen, and
> - what will be the sign of Your coming and of the end of the age?”

Thus, while I agree that Luke 17:20-37 and Luke 21:25-28 are both discussing signs and warnings of Jesus' second coming, that does not prevent Luke 21:20-24 discussing the destruction of Jerusalem.

Jesus great sermon in Matt 24, Mark 13, Luke 21 essentially tells the disciples that the social conditions in Jerusalem before its destruction by the Romans will be very similar to those in the times preceding Jesus second advent.  We can use the historicity of the first event to learn about the second event.

Put another way, Jesus' warning about the last days, uses three historic examples:

- as in the days of Noah
- as it was in the time of Sodom and Gomorrah,
- as it will be at the destruction of Jerusalem

... people were going about their ordinary daily lives ("eating and drink, marrying and giving in marriage, etc) and were blissfully ignorant, even oblivious to the approaching cataclysmic event; and it will be also true of the end times just before Jesus returns.

Jesus warns us to be ready.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would you understand Luke 17:31-33, which warns those on the housetop not to get his goods similar to Lot's wife? Doesn't this sound like Christians would need to flee immediately, suggestive of attack from another nation?

Comment: @TheEditor - good question - I think the lesson of Lot and his family is that we must not be so attached to our worldly goods that we do not want to leave to be with Jesus.

Answer (score 2):

Please allow me to offer a very brief exegesis as it is presented in the four gospels. If you need further explanation, I will be happy to provide it.

Outline by Glen Rogers

Jesus is explaining the Great Tribulation that was to befall Jerusalem. Combining the synoptic gospels gives us a comprehensive account of this discussion. Matthew 24, Mark 13, and Luke 21.

I. Jesus Foretold the Destruction of the Temple.

A.  Those present were Jesus, Peter, Andrew, James, and John.

Combining all three gospel accounts we see there are five questions asked by these four men in response to Jesus' revelation about the destruction of the temple.

1. “When will these things be?”
2. “What will be the sign when these things are about to take place?” Luke 21:7
3. “What will be the sign when all these things will be fulfilled?” Mark 13:4
4. “What will be the sign of your coming?” They immediately equated the destruction of the temple to the idea of the coming of the Lord.
5. What will be the sign “of the end of the age?” They equated the destruction of the temple with the end of that age. Everything that follows in this chapter is in direct response to these five questions.

B.  Context specifics: These things are

1. Event specific – He is describing the destruction of Jerusalem.
2. Time specific – They were limited to that generation.
3. Geographically specific – They were limited to Jerusalem/Judea.
4. Target specific – The temple
5. Instrument Specific – The Roman Armies, Luke 21:20

C.  Jesus presents five deceptive things which he tells them would not be relevant to the time of the destruction of the temple, yet would precede that event. He has already warned them in verse four not to be deceived about the nature of these things.

> “See to it that no one deceives you. For many will come in My name, claiming, ‘I am the Christ,’ and will deceive many. You will
> hear of wars and rumors of wars, but see to it that you are not
> alarmed. These things must happen, but the end is still to come.
> Nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom. There
> will be famines and earthquakes in various places. All these are the
> beginning of birth pains.” 4-8

1. There would be false Messiahs ”claiming, ‘I am the Christ.’” We know these were numerous in Judea prior to the siege of Jerusalem which we will look at later.
2. There would be “wars and rumors of war.” Before the fall of Jerusalem, the entire world was at war with Rome, but more specifically, there was constant tension and rebellion between the Jews and Rome over a number of issues that the Jews found egregious.
3. Nations would rise up against one another.
4. There would be famines. Famines raged in Judea in the mid first century, Acts 11:28.
5. There would be earthquakes.

There were many in the region of Asia Minor and Horn, etc during the reign of Nero. Mt. Vesuvius erupted in AD 79 killing an estimated 16,000 people.

6. Pestilence

All of these were things they would witness in their lifetime that would precede the destruction of the temple; but Jesus tells them they were not to be deceived by these things for they were only the beginning of birth pains. These were thus, not indicators of the end but would have been proclaimed so by the false christs.

II. Relevant Events to Precede the Destruction of Jerusalem,
These would specifically target Christians.

A.  The apostles would be delivered up to death.

> "Then shall they deliver you up unto tribulation and shall kill you:
> and all of you shall be hated of all the nations for my name's sake."

Peter, James, and Paul, died under Nero before AD 70. According to tradition, many of the apostles died before AD 70, but not all. Some apostles survived until near the end of the first century. So, some of the apostles lived long enough the witness the events Jesus described in this chapter just as Jesus said they would. John was one such apostle. He was the only apostle we can verify who died a natural death.

B.  There would be global opposition to Christianity and betrayal.

> “And then many will be offended, will betray one another, and will
> hate one another.”

C.  There would be apostasy. “And shall lead many astray.” This was well documented in the epistles during the days of Paul and Peter. 2 Peter 3, Galatians 1, Acts. 20, 1 John 4:1-6, Jude 17 and 19, and Hebrews. 6:4-8.

D.  There would be an increase in lawlessness. We see the fulfillment of this in Paul's writings.

> “For the mystery of lawlessness is already at work; only he who now
> restrains will do so until he is taken out of the way.” 2
> Thessalonians 2:7.

E.  “The love of many would grow cold.” This was the charge Jesus leveled against the Church at Ephesus in Revelation 2:4 “But I have this against you, that you have left your first love.”

F.  During this time, there would be the global expansion of the gospel. We know this happened within the life time of the apostle Paul.

1. This begin in Acts 2 when Jews who had assembled “from every nation under heaven” believed the gospel. After the celebrations of Pentecost were over, these new converts took that gospel home with them when they returned to their respective nations.
2. In Colossians 1:23, Paul affirms,

> “If indeed you continue in the faith firmly established and steadfast,
> and not moved away from the hope of the gospel that you have heard,
> which was proclaimed in all creation under heaven, and of which I,
> Paul, was made a minister,”

Colossians was written between AD 62-64.
3.  In Romans 1:8 he says,

> “First, I thank my God through Jesus Christ for you all, because your
> faith is being proclaimed throughout the whole world.”

Romans was written in AD 60.
4.  In  1 Thessalonians 1:8 Paul declares,

> “For the word of the Lord has sounded forth from you, not only in
> Macedonia and Achaia, but also in every place your faith toward God
> has gone forth, so that we have no need to say anything.”

1 Thessalonians was written in AD 63.

III. Revealed Indicators, 15-22

Jesus then gave them some revealed indicators that specifically pointed to the end of which he spoke in verses one and two; and with this he issues a warning to the apostles.

> “Therefore, when you see the ‘abomination of desolation,’ spoken of by
> Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place (whoever reads, let him
> understand), then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains.
> Let him who is on the housetop not go down to take anything out of his
> house. And let him who is in the field not go back to get his clothes.
> But woe to those who are pregnant and to those who are nursing babies
> in those days! And pray that your flight may not be in winter or on
> the Sabbath. For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not
> been since the beginning of the world until this time, no, nor ever
> shall be. And unless those days were shortened, no flesh would be
> saved; but for the elect’s sake those days will be shortened.”

A.  “The ‘abomination of desolation,’ spoken of by Daniel,” Daniel 9:26-27,

> “And after the sixty-two weeks Messiah shall be cut off, but not for
> Himself; and the people of the prince who is to come shall destroy the
> city and the sanctuary. The end of it shall be with a flood, and till
> the end of the war desolations are determined. Then he shall confirm a
> covenant with many for one week; but in the middle of the week, He
> shall bring an end to sacrifice and offering. And on the wing of
> abominations shall be one who makes desolate, even until the
> consummation, which is determined, is poured out on the desolate.”

Jesus applies the “abomination of desolation” spoken of in Daniel 9:26-27 to the impending destruction of Jerusalem and the temple. That event would be witnessed by that generation. He warned them,

> “Therefore, when you see the ‘abomination of desolation,’ spoken of by
> Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place” (whoever reads, let
> him understand), then let those who are in Judea flee to the
> mountains.”

The “abomination of desolation” would be the standards of the Roman army that would be placed in the “holy place.” This is confirmed by Luke 21:20-21.

> “But when you see Jerusalem surrounded by armies, then know that its
> desolation is near. Then let those who are in Judea flee to the
> mountains, let those who are in the midst of her depart, and let not
> those who are in the country enter her.”

When that generation saw the Roman army coming to surround Jerusalem, they were to immediately flee to the mountains in order to escape the judgment that God was sending upon Jerusalem.

Jesus confirmed his covenant, the New Covenant, for one week. In the middle of the week (3 ½ years into his ministry) he was “cut off” – crucified. This put an end to the sacrifices and offerings of the old covenant. The Jews would continue in vain to offer sacrifices that had been rendered null and void by the crucifixion of Christ for another 40 years until the destruction of the temple. It would still be another 3½ years from the crucifixion until the completion of the covenant week when the Samaritans and the Gentiles were brought in with the conversion of the Samaritans and the Ethiopian Eunuch in Acts 8.

B.  “Then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains.” Christians fled to the mountains of Pela, 20. See also Zechariah 14:5-7.

C.

> “Let him who is on the housetop not go down to take anything out of
> his house. Let him who is in the field not go back to get his
> clothes.”

In order to escape the impending destruction of Jerusalem, time was of the essence. Jesus warned them to flee immediately.

D.

> “Woe to those who are pregnant and to those who are nursing babies in
> those days.”

Escape would have been slow and difficult for the women who were pregnant and those with small children.

E.  “Pray that your flight may not be in winter.” Having to deal with the harshness of the winter would have made their escape more difficult in view of the extreme urgency and hardship of travel, 17-22.

F.  “Or on the Sabbath.” The gates of the city would be closed preventing any escape from the city.

G.  Why the urgency?

1.

> “For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been since
> the beginning of the world until this time, no, nor ever shall be.”

In Luke 21:20, Luke records an even clearer picture of this.

> “But when you see Jerusalem surrounded by armies, recognize that her
> desolation is near.”

This gives definition to the abomination of desolation of which Jesus speaks in Matthew's account from Daniel 9.

2.

> “And unless those days were shortened, no flesh would be saved; but
> for the elect’s sake those days will be shortened.”

It is important to remember the temporal and geographical context to which this statement belongs. As bad as this destruction was, it would be limited in both time and severity. Had the Lord not shortened those days, no one in the city or even those who had escaped would have survived. The elect refers to those Jews who had embraced the gospel and fled the city. (See Benson on this verse.) This would be an event that at least some of the apostles would witness.

IV. The Proclamation of False Messiah’s, 23-25

Notice, the warning of encountering false messiahs was to the apostles.

> “Then if anyone says to you, ‘Look, here is the Christ!’ or ‘There!’
> do not believe it. For false christs and false prophets will rise and
> show great signs and wonders to deceive, if possible, even the elect.
> See, I have told you beforehand. Therefore, if they say to you, ‘Look,
> He is in the desert!’ do not go out; or ‘Look, He is in the inner
> rooms!’ do not believe it.”

A.  Many false messiahs rose up during that time: Among these were such men as:

1. Judah the Galilean of about AD 6 or 7 is mentioned in Acts 5:37. He is also mentioned by Josephus.
2. Theudas, from AD 45, is mentioned in Acts 5:36. He too, is mentioned by Josephus in Antiquites.
3. There was also the unnamed Egyptian mentioned in Acts 21:38 as

> ”the Egyptian who incited a rebellion some time ago and led four
> thousand members of the ‘Assassins’ into the wilderness?”

4. The most prominent false messiah to arise was Shimon Ben-Kosiba in AD 66 and died during the destruction of the Jerusalem in AD 70. (You might also see Benson)

Bear in mind, in the mind of the first century Jew, the Messiah was thought to be someone who would deliver them from Roman oppression, not save them from their sins. Many such men of that time rose up in rebellion against Rome and were destroyed. Jesus was warning his apostles not to go after these men.

B.  False prophets

Josephus represents the false prophets of that time as "magicians and sorcerers." He says they led the people out into the deserts promising miracles of deliverance.

Gill relates the account of one Akaba who was one of such false prophets. Akiba attempted to persuade the people to embrace Barcochab as the Messiah applying many prophecies to Barcochab.

Comment: +1 - Very well laid out, oldhermit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if we assume that Luke 17:26–30 describes the destruction of Jerusalem, then the next verse, which begins with "in that day," must certainly refer to the destruction of Jerusalem, not the Last Days.

This begs the question as to how Jerusalem's demise resembled the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah. Starting with vs. 26, Jesus said:

> As it was in the days of Noah, so will it be in the days of the Son of
> man. They ate, they drank, they married, they were given in marriage,
> until the day when Noah entered the ark, and the flood came and
> destroyed them all. Likewise as it was in the days of Lot—they ate,
> they drank, they bought, they sold, they planted, they built...

This describes people carrying on their normal lives rather than repenting and preparing for disaster. In both Noah's day and Lot's day, Jewish sources hold that the people were offered an opportunity to repent prior to the destruction. It is not possible to tell from the text if Jesus had something like this in mind, but it is known that Christians in Jerusalem did not join the revolt. It could be speculated that God intended for the populace of Jerusalem to resist the "war party" and listen to those who counseled making peace with Rome, including Jewish-Christian prophets who may still have been active.

In any case if the assumption is made that the verses in question refer to the destruction of Jerusalem the following verse must certainly refer back to the situation of the time of Noah and of Lot. It would imply that the people of Jerusalem and its environs should quickly flee the coming destruction. Many of them indeed did so, but not until it was too late for tens of thousands who were killed.

---

*Note: I do not personally share the assumption the OP asks us to make.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since Luke 17:31-33 warns those on the housetop not to get their goods but to remember Lot's wife, doesn't this sound like Christians would need to flee immediately? If so, doesn't this suggest an attack from another nation is in view?

Comment: Rome would be the other nation. At this point in time Christians who lived in Jerusalem were part of the Jewish people and had to either flee the Roman army or suffer the destruction. Numbers of victims vary widely. Jews (including Jewish Christians) were sometimes killed by Zealots who saw them as collaborators but the Romans certainly did most of the killing. https://www.worldhistory.org/article/823/the-great-jewish-revolt-of-66-ce/

Answer (score 1):

Luke 17:26-31 describes Jesus second coming, not refers to the destruction of Jerusalem in 70AD.

Jesus had told what is like what the Day comes;

> Matthew 24:44 So you also must be ready, because the Son of Man will come at an hour when you do not expect him.

So His second coming has two key factors;

1. It comes in a sudden that most people unprepared.
2. When people aware of His coming, there is no time to prepare.

In Luke 17:26-31, Jesus quoted the flood and the destruction of Sodom, both fulfilled the two key factors. In Luke 17:31, Jesus said on that day, no one who was on the housetop should go down to get their possessions, and no one in the field should go back for anything. The reason is simply the time is up. There is nothing more they can do if they were not prepared.

Luke 17:26-31 does not refer to the destruction of Jerusalem in 70AD, as it does not fulfilled the above key factors. Actually Jerusalem was well prepared to resist the great army of Rome, that they survive for three months. After the destruction, Jerusalem still exists until today, unlike the flood that swept the world to a new creation, and Sodom no longer exist.